# Weird background clipping behaviour when floating div resizes

Tags: html, css, background

HTML page has a background image. Nav menu on left expands on hover to reveal elements. Menu has transparent background.

When the menu grows it clips the background image and moves it down the page behind the menu.

Reduced it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/GgXXh/

Is the background clipping expected behaviour that I don't understand, or is this a browser bug (Firefox 9)?

It seems to requires that the body be set `overflow-y: scroll` and the menu `float: left` to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really looks like FF bug. Reproduces with FF 7 also.
Reproduces also without `overflow-y: scroll` on body.

On Chrome works well.

Changing `background-position` to `top center` fixes the clipping and moving down on the background:

http://jsfiddle.net/GgXXh/8/